# Is there a name for this sequence property?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, terminology

Consider a sequence $\left(a_i\right)_{i=1, \ldots, N}$ of real numbers. Define the property $P$ as follows:

- the sequence $\left(a_i\right)$ has the property $P$ if there is a $c \in \{1, \ldots,N\}$ such:

  i)   $a_{i} \le a_{j}$, for all $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, c\}$ with $i < j$

  ii)   $a_{i} \ge a_{j}$, for all $i,j \in \{c, \ldots, N\}$ with $i < j$

  holds.

In another words, $\left(a_i\right)$ is such that the subsequence $(a_1, \ldots, a_c)$ is non-decreasing and the subsequence $(a_c, \ldots, a_N)$ is non-increasing. The value of $c$ does not matter for me, just the existence of such index.

My question is the following:

Is there a usual or standard name for the property $P$?

Bonus question:

Let $f:[a,b] \to [c,d]$ be a real value function and let $(x_i)_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ be a increasing sequence with $x_i, \ldots, x_N \in [a,b]$.

define $b_i = f(x_i) $ for $i=1, \ldots, N$

It seems to me that:

- if $f$ is a concave function, then $(b_i)_{i=1, \ldots, N}$ has the property $P$.

Dut I do not know how prove (or refute) such implication. Can someone help me?

Comment: I believe bitonic sequence is a usual name in programming. Searching it in google will give mostly programming-related results though.

Comment: This is a [unimodular sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207419/number-of-unimodular-sequnces)

Comment: The term I'm more familiar with is "[unimodal sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality)".